# How to make a refresh on a var python / Ruffus

Tags: python, bioinformatics, ruffus

I'm new to the field of bioinformatics, and a Python beginner.

I'm using a framework called Ruffus to run a pipeline making files navigating through tools to have an interesting output.

In a part of my pipeline (3rd step) I need to do a little workaround to make Ruffus take in account my files : the tool used changes the output name pretty much arbitrary.

My issue is the following : I have to run a first time the pipeline to make it run until the 3rd step, where it says that everyfile is done. And then when I re-run, it goes from 3rd to the end.
I think the issue is I use glob that takes regarding a specific pattern, that glob function should be run at the beggining of my script, but the files I'm looking for (.*avinput) are not created yet. Then once I re-run it, they are, and then the process can go on. But that's not realiable.

How can I "force" a var like that to wait until a specific moment to be run, either to re-run it when reached a certain step?

Best,

```
from ruffus import *
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import re
import glob
import time
import termcolor



#====================================
#
#Input area
#
#
#====================================

#Create a method to get all the files from the folder
input_files = (["/genetics/ongoing_work/pipeline/78_14_TR_p_BWA_mem_PIC_conv_ord_mdup_group_recal_rawvariants_Joint_INDEL_recalibrated_extracted_filter_appl.vcf",
               "/genetics/ongoing_work/pipeline/78_14_TR_p_BWA_mem_PIC_conv_ord_mdup_group_recal_rawvariants_Joint_SNP_recalibrated_extracted_filter_appl.vcf"])
# DIRECTORIES
outdir = '/genetics/ongoing_work/pipeline'
annovar_db='/genetics/apps/annovar/humandb/'

#SOFTWARES
gatk = '/genetics/apps/gatk3.8/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar'
convert2annovar='/genetics/apps/annovar/convert2annovar.pl'
annotate_variation='/genetics/apps/annovar/annotate_variation.pl'
table_annovar='/genetics/apps/annovar/table_annovar.pl'

#FILES
reference_genome = '/genetics/reference/ucsc.hg19.fasta'


# ---------- 1st step -----------
#  Filter Low Quality Genotypes
#  Filter Low Quality Genotypes
#  GATK
#
# ---------------------------

@transform(input_files, formatter("([^/]+).vcf$"), os.path.join(outdir, "{1[0]}_flqg.vcf"))

def LowQualityGenotype(input_file, output_file):
    print(termcolor.colored(' ---------- 1st step ----------- \n  \
  Filter Low Quality Genotypes \n \
  Filter Low Quality Genotypes \n  \
  GATK \n  \
 \n  \
 --------------------------- \n','red'))

    subprocess.run("java -jar {tool} \
    -T VariantFiltration \
    -R {ref} \
    -V {i_file} \
    -G_filter 'GQ < 20.0' \
    -G_filterName 'LowQG' \
    -o {o_file}".format(
        o_file=output_file,
        i_file=input_file,
        tool=gatk,
        ref=reference_genome
    ), shell=True)


# ---------- 2nd step -----------
#  Convert to Avinput
#  ANNOVAR
# UPDATE TO FIX
# ---------------------------


@subdivide(LowQualityGenotype, formatter("([^/]+).vcf$"), os.path.join(outdir, "{1[0]}.avinput"))

def ConvertAvinput(input_file, output_files):
    subprocess.run("perl {tool} \
    -format vcf4 -allsample\
    -withzyg \
    -includeinfo \
    {i_file} \
    -outfile {o_file}".format(
        o_file=output_files,
        i_file=input_file,
        tool=convert2annovar,
    ), shell=True)
    #modifying outputs because 2 gives 4 with the samples names in it

    file_list_avinput = glob.glob(outdir+'/*.avinput')
    print('Impression du glob')
    print(file_list_avinput)
    #use of glob to get all the files created
    for i in file_list_avinput:
        if i:
            os.rename(i, re.sub('(.avinput)(?:\.)(.{5})(?:.*)',"_sample_\\2\\1",i))

    time.sleep(3)





# ---------- 3rd step -----------
#  Filter 1000G
#  ANNOVAR
#
# ---------------------------
pre1000g_files = glob.glob(outdir + '/*.avinput')
print('LIGNES POUR PRE1000G')
print(pre1000g_files)


@follows(ConvertAvinput)

@subdivide(pre1000g_files, formatter("([^/]+).avinput"),
           os.path.join(outdir, "{1[0]}_1000G_filtered"))

def Filter1000G(input_file, output_files):
    print('LIGNES POUR PRE1000G')
    print(pre1000g_files)
    subprocess.run("perl {tool} \
    -filter \
    -dbtype 1000g2015aug_eur \
    -buildver hg19 \
    -maf {maf_freq} \
    -out {o_file} \
    {i_file} \
    {annodb} \
    -outfile {o_file}".format(
        o_file=output_files,
        i_file=input_file,
        maf_freq=0.03,
        annodb=annovar_db,
        tool=annotate_variation
    ), shell=True)

    os.rename(output_files+'.hg19_EUR.sites.2015_08_filtered',output_files[0:-8]+'filtered')
    os.rename(output_files + '.hg19_EUR.sites.2015_08_dropped', output_files[0:-7]+'_dropped')


# ---------- 4th step -----------
#  Filter InHouse
#  ANNOVAR
#
# ---------------------------


@transform(Filter1000G,  formatter("([^/]+)_filtered"),
                                        os.path.join(outdir, "{1[0]}_Norge_filtered"))
def FilterInHouse(input_file, output_file):

    subprocess.run("perl {tool} \
    -filter \
    -dbtype generic \
    -genericdbfile nimblegen_v3_and_v2_combined_jul2015.singleallelic.avinput.AC_gt_5 \
    -buildver hg19 \
    -out {o_file} \
    {i_file} \
    {annodb} \
    -outfile {o_file}".format(
        o_file=output_file,
        i_file=input_file,
        maf_freq=0.005,
        annodb=annovar_db,
        tool=annotate_variation
    ), shell=True)
    os.rename(output_file+'.hg19_generic_filtered',output_file[0:-8]+'filtered')
    os.rename(output_file + '.hg19_generic_dropped', output_file[0:-7]+'_dropped')
pipeline_run(FilterInHouse)
```

Comment: Can't you just make `pre1000g_files` the output from `ConvertAvinput` and then use `@follows` as normal?

Comment: Oops sorry Chris, Haven't seen your comment. 
Nope, actually if I do that, it tells me that the file is not found, probably because Avinput adds the sample name in it, so weirdly it can't recognise it. 
I say weirdly because I thought it was doing a glob.. 

Currently I am trying at the end of each function to update a glob function what will update var, but it's not working very well so far..